# Elasticsearch date math query that combines an actual date and math expression

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I have a timestamp in ms `new Date('2023-03-09').getTime()` which outputs 1678320000000. How do I use this specific timestamp to do an ElasticSearch query to find any documents from that timestamp to 1 minute before it using a Date Math expression? I seem to run into the same problem when formatting the date as a String such as `2023-03-09-1m`. I tried an ES query like this:

```
"range": { 
  "@timestamp": {
    "gte": "1678320000000-1m", 
    "lt": "1678320000000"
  } 
}
```

But it just seems to get the error

```
"reason": {
  "type": "parse_exception",
  "reason": "failed to parse date field [1678320000000-1m] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]",
  "caused_by": {
    "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason": "Unrecognized chars at the end of [1678320000000-1m]: [320000000-1m]"
  }
}
```

While if I use the normal date math with `now`, the query succeeds.

```
"range": { 
  "@timestamp": {
    "gte": "now-1m", 
    "lt": "1678320000000"
  } 
}
```

Is there some way to combine both the date math and a math expression within a query?

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
"range": { 
  "@timestamp": {
    "gte": "1678320000000||-1m", 
    "lt": "1678320000000"
  } 
}
```

[Date Math documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math) says

> The expression starts with an anchor date, which can either be now, or
> a date string ending with ||.